# Error with the malloc command in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

my Excercice is to initalise space from the heap in function1(); and to create an array there. In the main I have to print the array. What have I done wrong?

**CODE**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int functionOne(int size);

 int main()
 {

     int size = 0,i;
     scanf("%d",&size);

     int *arrsize = functionOne(size);
     printf("rueckgabe %d",arrsize);

     int arr [*arrsize];

     arr[0] = 7;
     arr[1] = 2;
     arr[2] = 3;
     arr[3] = 4;
     arr[4] = 5;

     for(i=0; i<size; i++)
     {
         printf("[%d]",arr[i]);
     }
}

int functionOne(int size)
{
    int *arr;
    arr = NULL;

    arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    return arr; 
}
```

Comment: For starters your function declares it returns an `int` value and you are attempting to return a pointer to `int`

Comment: You did not format your code correctly. Once you do the formatting, you'll see that you are missing a closing curly brace after `main`.

Comment: You're missing a `}` to end `main()`.

Comment: Further `int arr [*arrsize];` makes no sense in your code, `arrsize` is a pointer to `int` (which seems to be an array itself), yet you haven't assigned any values to the pointed to memory

Comment: what do i have to change?

Comment: Don't use `scanf()` to read (potentially malformed) user input; read whole lines with `fgets()` and parse in-memory (e.g. with `strtol()`). **Never** use `scanf()` without checking its return value.

Comment: Do you understand what is being said in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is on the line `printf("rueckgabe %d",arrsize);` you are printing the address returned by other function - that too using wrong format specifier.

Suppose you allocated memory for `4` `int` using the other function `functionOne` and the memory of the allocated chunk is being returned - now when you do `*arrsize` you are basically accessing the `0`th positional `int` value. But as it is uninitialized - the value of it is indeterminate.

Earlier you were declaring VLA with uninitialized value. This is *undefined behavior*. Also there is no meaning printing the contents of the variable length array unless you initialize them (i.e.,`printf("[%d]",arr[i]);`).
Return value of the function `functionOne` is `int` but you are returning `int*`.

There are many other things you can follow in the code, like correcting the indentation - checking the return value of `malloc` and changing the signature of `main` from `int main()` to `int main(void)`.

I have added some demo code showing whatever I have mentioned above:

#### Edit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int* functionOne(int size);

int main(void)
{

    int size = 0;
    if( scanf("%d",&size)!= 1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if( size <= 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in input [size]\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    int *arr = functionOne(size);
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
        arr[i]=i;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i<size; i++){
        printf("arr[%zu] = %d \n",i,arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}

int* functionOne(int size)
{
    int *arr;
    arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    if( arr == NULL && size > 0){
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return arr; 
}
```